# Could I hide the captions from getting raised evertime i move my cursor over the video, that's really annoying

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

```
`
! 9/16/2019 https://www.youtube.com
www.youtube.com##.ytp-chrome-controls
www.youtube.com##.gradient-bottom
www.youtube.com##.ytp-chrome-bottom
www.youtube.com##.ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink ytp-title-
www.youtube.com##.fullerscreen-link
www.youtube.com##.ytp-share-icon
www.youtube.com##.Channel watermark
www.youtube.com##.ytp-bezel-text-hide
www.youtube.com##.ytp-gradient-bottom
www.youtube.com##.ytp-cards-button-icon
www.youtube.com##.Channel watermark
www.youtube.com##.annotation annotation-type-custom iv-branding
www.youtube.com##.branding-img-container
www.youtube.com##.ytp-cards-teaser
www.youtube.com##.ytp-title-text
www.youtube.com##.ytp-chrome-top-buttons
www.youtube.com##.ytp-gradient-top
```

`

I have blocked these classes in youtube.com:-
I have put these classes to be blocked to other things away that the youtube media player has. Now i need to get rid of the captions being raised evertime I hover my mouse over the video. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the captions to relocate them, and by experiment it seems like if they are placed anywhere in the upper two-thirds of the screen they will not move when the playback controls appear.

Comment: thanks for your response, but its dragging the captions doen't work at all, it get dragged anywhere I drag it, but in the next moment it gets re-placed at where it was earlier.
Suggest anything else, it bugs me a lot...Help is appreciated.